# Python optional input + print

Tags: python, python-3.3

I'm very new to python and came across a problem: I need to make an optional input. Here's my code:

```
elif direction == "east":
    print("text1")
    var0 = input()
    if var0 == "read paper" or var0 == "open paper":
        print("text2")
```

But, you don't need to input and print text2. You can just pass right by it and carry on. I tried various statments such as continue and break, but break made me go back too far. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just check if it's empty?

```
if var0 == "read paper" or var0 == "open paper" or var0 == "":
    print("text2")
```

Tips: Use `in` for this:

```
if var0 in ("read paper", "open paper", ""):
```

Comment: That way, the user would have to input a blank statement. They would literally just have to press enter.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add another check before, where the user can make a choice if he wants to pursue the event or not?:

```
elif direction == "east":
  print ('going east...')
  user_choice = input("You reach location 'x'. Would you like to check it out? yes / no \n")
  # 'yes' continues, everything else passes
  if user_choice == 'yes':
    var0 = input('You see a paper on the ground. What do you do? \n')
    if var0 in ("read paper", "open paper"):
      print ('text2')
  else:
    print ('walking away')
```

I'm not sure what you mean by 'optional input' but in python 'input()' stops your program until the user inputs some text (or not) and hits 'Enter'. So as soon as your program reaches line 'var0 = input()' some user input is expected.

Comment: Yes, that is genius! I can insert a text asking if they want to open it. Thanks!